# How to check if String is a Float separated by a comma?

Tags: java, regex

I have an ArrayList of Strings which contains various data. It is filled with numbers, decimal numbers, simple strings and so one(but all of them are stored as a Strings).

My goal is to make an regular expression which matches only those Strings which have following data *,* (floats separated by a comma or simple integers) :

```
"1"
"0" 
"120000"
"1,23133"
"21312,9"
```

My second goal is that regular expression will return false when it finds something like this:

```
"[82903] some_text"
"Release 12.5"  //yes, it is separated by a dot
```

I was trying with this pattern:

```
String pattern = "(\\d+(\\,\\d+)?)";
```

But it doesn't work properly in my case. I was trying with NumberFormat but it fails when it sees "," instead of ".".

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to match *only* numbers, or any string *containing* numbers?

Comment: The `NumberFormatException` can be fixed by specifying a `Locale` which supports `,` instead of `.`, like the `Locale.FRENCH`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try with the following pattern, below is a sample test of mine :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "([-+]?[0-9]*,?[0-9]+)";
    String x = "1,23132";

    System.out.println(x.matches(pattern));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this with `12.5` - it maches `12` and `5` separately.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using `DecimalFormat` see this code:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();

DecimalFormatSymbols commaSeperateFormat = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
commaSeperateFormat.setDecimalSeparator(',');

decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(commaSeperateFormat );

String[] testCases = {"1", "0", "120000", "1,23133", "21312,9"};
for (String t : testCases) {
    Number parsedNumber = decimalFormat.parse(t);
    float theFloatNumber = parsedNumber.floatValue();

    System.out.println(theFloatNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex (anchor it to the beginning and end):

```
String pattern = "^(\\d+(?:,\\d+)?)$";
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lL9wD5/1). If the numbers can occur everywhere in your string, you could as well use word boundaries and an alternation:

```
String pattern = "\\b(?:\\d+\\.\\d+|(\\d+(?:,\\d+)?))\\b";
```

With this approach use only the numbers captured in the first group, see a [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lL9wD5/2)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also want to capture the two parts, right? You could try this:

```
String pattern = "([+-]?\\d+)(?:,(\\d+))?"
```

Answer (score 0):

this will remove all non numeric characters as well as figuring out whether it's a cultural decimal with comma as a decimal separator or a dot as it

```
public static decimal RemoveAllNonNumericCharacters(this string input)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en");
        string regex = string.Empty;
        if (input.Contains(",") && input.Contains("."))
        {
            if (input.IndexOf(".") > input.IndexOf(","))
            {
                culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                regex = "[^-.0-9]";
            }
            else
            {
                culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
                regex = "[^-,0-9]";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (input.Contains(",") && input.Split(',').Length == 2)
            {
                culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
                regex = "[^-,0-9]";
            }

            if (input.Contains(".") && input.Split('.').Length == 2)
            {
                culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                regex = "[^-.0-9]";
            }
        }
        return decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(input, regex, string.Empty), culture);
    }
```